# Filter Data based on same ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a model class

```
public class Model
  {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string files { get; set; }
   }
```

I have a controller class that populates the data from database into this model

```
 List<Model> model = new List<Model>();    
 while (reader.Read()){
     var om = new Model();

     if (reader != null)
         {
          om.name = reader.GetString(0);
          om.files = reader.GetString(1);
          model.Add(om)               
   }
```

How can I filter and combine all files that have the similar  first names?

I read about linq and tried this

```
  var jm = om.name
    .Where(o => om.name.Contains(o))
    .Select() ;
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove the duplicates from `List<Model> model ...`?

Comment: look into Linqs "GroupBy" clause...

Comment: I do not want to remove duplicates. I want to group  based on same names.

Comment: I removed all references to ASP.Net because they're not relevant. The meaning of *files that have the similar first names* is not clear. For starters, what's in `files`? What does the content of a typical `Model` look like?

Comment: @Gert Arnold A user might have several file names. For Example,                                              Bob \c\users\bob\file.txt, Bob \d\tester.csv , John \c\users\John\apple.txt . I want to combine all Bobs files together and all of Johns files together as well.

Comment: @JohnMarshall, see my answer below. Would that work for you?

Comment: @nurchi, Yes, this works as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
var grouped = model.GroupBy(m => m.name).ToArray();
```

This will create an object `grouped` of type `IGrouping<string, Model>[]` (array of `IGrouping...`)
`.ToArray()` is optional and if you remove it, you get `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Model>>`, but don't let the nested `<>` scare you.

The items in your original list are grouped by name, so the group will have `Key` property that will be the same for each element in the group.

To print the results, for example:

```
foreach(var group in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Printing group: {group.Key}");
    foreach(var model in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\tName: {model.name}, File: {model.file}");
    }
}
```

Note that each element in a group is a collection of your model objects.

Use debugger to see what that structure looks like and if you need more help - ask...

Comment: In that case, please mark one as answer :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Model

```
public class Model
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public IList<string> files { get; set; }
}
```

Use a Dictionary.

```
var models = new Dictionary<string, Model>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    var om = new Model();

    if (reader != null)
    {
        var name = reader.GetString(0);
        var file = reader.GetString(1);

        if (models.Contains(name))
            models[name].files.Add(file); 
        else
        {
            models.Add(name, new Model
            {
                name = name,
                files = new List<string>{files}
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can pull out a combined list with LINQ:

```
var peopleFileLists = models.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
foreach(var person in peopleFileLists)
{
   foreach(var file in person.files)
     Console.WriteLine(person.name + "-" + file);
}
```

Comment: How are you able to view the pairs in models? foreach(var row in models){}}

Comment: How would you combine, I am not sure I understand this section: if(models.Contains(name)) models[name].files += files; Can you explain this section further

Comment: Yeah I didn't understand what you meant by combine either.  But now I think I understand that you are wanting to maintain a list of files there.  I'll update my example